# When does assist count as kill?

Tags: battlefield-4

I've seen the message quite a few times, having dealt significant damage to the enemy I get  `squad assists counts as kill`.

But what are exact requirements? How much damage is enough? And is that the case of all assists or only squad assists?

Comment: It's the case for all assists, not just squad.

Comment: Odd. I don't think I've ever had a "assist counts as kill" message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this webpage](http://bf4central.com/battlefield-4-point-system/) you have to deal at least 75 damage in order to get **Assist counts as kill**.

And it counts for all assists, not only squad

Comment: Actually I think I saw getting squad assist as kill as low as sixtysomething.

Comment: @vartec The webpage isn't correct for certain things. Like Headshot bonus is 25 and not 10. So I would take what they say with a grain of salt.

Comment: I've never gotten a squad kill assist lower than 75